# Xamarin Forms - how to make Entry tag read only (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Spent days on this, I am using Xamarin Forms Entry Tag and I need to make it appear readonly. (IsEnabled does not do this for my needs)

```
    <StackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource vehicleViewModel}">
            <Entry Placeholder="Make" x:Name="make" Text="{Binding VehicleMake}" Focused="VehicleMake_Focused" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just set `YourEntry.InputTransparent = true;` easy as it is.

Answer (score 2):

In the Focused event I added this.

```
        private async void VehicleMake_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            make.Focus();
            make.Unfocus();
//... more code
        }
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: this adds a little flicker effect to the control.